# Overlapping TextView on setText()

Tags: android, textview, overlap

I've a strange problem to set text in a TextView on Android.
When I try to set text in my code, the result is very strange. See the image to understand:

[image]

I've a layout as is:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/LayoutWorkingHWeek"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LayoutMonthlyHH">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="@string/TotWorkingHH"
            android:gravity="left"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtWorkingHH"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="00:00"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

After, I set the text in my TextView by code:

```
String tothmonthextra = "10:00"
TextView txttothmextra = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.txtWorkingHH);
txttothmextra.setText(tothmonthextra);
```

I don't understand where is the problem...

Thanks!!!

EDIT:

I've a custom view with more than one textview. The problem appears on all textview...

This is the code:

```
class CustomCard_General_Data_Monthly extends Card
    {
        protected TextView txttothm, txttothworkingm, txttothworkingm_real, txttothmextra, txttothmextra_real, txtDiffextra;
        String tothmonth, tothworkingmonth, tothworkingmonth_real, tothmonthextra, tothmonthextra_real, diffextra;

        public CustomCard_General_Data_Monthly(Context context, String Tothmonth, String Tothworkingmonth, String Tothworkingmonth_real, String Tothmonthextra,
                                               String Tothmonthextra_real, String Diffextra)
        {
            this(context, R.layout.card_summary_month);
            this.tothmonth = Tothmonth;
            this.tothworkingmonth = Tothworkingmonth;
            this.tothworkingmonth_real = Tothworkingmonth_real;
            this.tothmonthextra = Tothmonthextra;
            this.tothmonthextra_real = Tothmonthextra_real;
            this.diffextra = Diffextra;
        }

        public CustomCard_General_Data_Monthly(Context context, int innerLayout) {
            super(context, innerLayout);
        }

        @Override
        public void setupInnerViewElements(ViewGroup parent, View view)
        {
            txttothm = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.txtMonthlyHH);
            txttothworkingm = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.txtWorkingHH);
            txttothworkingm_real = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.txtWorkingHHReal);
            txttothmextra = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.txtExtraHH);
            txttothmextra_real = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.txtExtraHHreal);
            txtDiffextra = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.txtDiffExtraHH);

            txttothm.setText(tothmonth);
            txttothworkingm.setText(tothworkingmonth);
            txttothworkingm_real.setText(tothworkingmonth_real);
            txttothmextra.setText(tothmonthextra);
            txttothmextra_real.setText(tothmonthextra_real);
            txtDiffextra.setText(diffextra);
        }
    }
```

The Layout card_summary_month is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/LayoutMonthlyHH"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="@string/HoursPerMonth"
            android:gravity="left"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMonthlyHH"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/Hours_default"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/LayoutWorkingHWeek"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LayoutMonthlyHH">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="@string/TotWorkingHH"
            android:gravity="left"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtWorkingHH"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/Hours_default"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/LayoutWorkingHWeekReal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LayoutWorkingHWeek">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="@string/TotWorkingHH_real"
            android:gravity="left"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtWorkingHHReal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/Hours_default"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/LayoutExtraHH"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LayoutWorkingHWeekReal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="@string/TotOverTimeReal"
            android:gravity="left"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtExtraHH"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/Hours_default"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/LayoutExtraHH_Real"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LayoutExtraHH">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="@string/TotOverTime"
            android:gravity="left"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtExtraHHreal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/Hours_default"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/LayoutDiffExtraHH"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LayoutExtraHH_Real">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="@string/TotDiffExtra"
            android:gravity="left"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDiffExtraHH"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/Hours_default"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

TextView `Id` you've entered is wrong. This should work.

```
String tothmonthextra = "10:00"
TextView txttothmextra = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.txtWorkingHH);
txttothmextra.setText(tothmonthextra);
```

Comment: No, ok...was wrong because I have more than one textview to set...sorry for distraction...I've edit the question! :)

Comment: if it was wrong  you will get a NPE @ `txttothmextra.setText(tothmonthextra);` coz `txttothmextra` would be null

Comment: @user3449772 post the place where you have the code and what is parent?

Comment: You may've a wrong `Parent`. Post the code of `onCreate()` method of Activity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late, but today I have got the same problem, and is something linked to RelativeLayout and it's parent... Put your relative layout inside a vertical LinearLayout and you solve the problem.